# PayPal Standard: how can I show a cart icon with amount and currency?

Tags: codeigniter, paypal

I am using CodeIgniter for PayPal Standard payments. Everything works fine, but I want PayPal to display a shopping cart icon with the amount and currency on its pages. Here is my code; how can I accomplish adding that?

```
    function buy($id){
        // Set variables for paypal form
        $returnURL = base_url() . 'paypal/success';
        $cancelURL = base_url() . 'paypal/cancel';
        $notifyURL = base_url() . 'paypal/ipn';

        // Get product data from the database
        $product = $this->product->getRows($id);

        // Get current user ID from the session
        // $userID = $_SESSION['userID'];

        // Add fields to paypal form
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('return', $returnURL);
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('cancel_return', $cancelURL);
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('notify_url', $notifyURL);
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('item_name', $product['name']);
        //        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('custom', $userID);
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('custom', 1);
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('item_number', $product['id']);
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('amount', $product['price']);

        // Render paypal form
        $this->paypal_lib->paypal_auto_form();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The sample you provided is considered an old/legacy solution by PayPal and is not recommended. So rather than tell you how to fiddle with something so old, I instead recommend you ditch the above function and use something nicer. Here is a demo that can act as a base for your front-end:

https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

It's all just HTML/JavaScript, so get it working on its own (in a .html file) first and then once it is working, save a backup copy, and then have your PHP application just output it when appropriate.

If you want individual item data to show, you will need to extend the "purchase_units" array.  Otherwise it will just be the amount and currency.  You can find a sample purchase_units array here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/set-up-transaction/  See the v2/orders API spec for the full documentation.